# How am I going to stop my page from reloading every time I click a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is what happened when I click my gridview after I search something then my next command is to get the data from gridview to textbox to edit the file and save it again but the select command is not working as it should be.. because the gridview is reloading and the file that i filtered is gone and it will select the first row in the gridview what  would I do? Here's my code for the select command

```
void getValue()
{
    // GridView1.SelectedIndex = isa;
    //gridview1Connection();

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    T_firstname.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Firstname") as Label).Text;
    T_middlename.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Middlename") as Label).Text;
    T_lastname.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Lastname") as Label).Text;
    T_age.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_Age") as Label).Text;
    T_id.Text = (row.FindControl("lbl_ID") as Label).Text;
    string gender = (row.FindControl("lbl_Sex") as Label).Text;

    if (gender == "FEMALE")
    {
        female_b.Checked = true;
        male_b.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        male_b.Checked = true;
        female_b.Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Should I use IsPostBack or viewstate? How am i going to set it  or code?

Here's my code for gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" 
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="581px" 
    onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" 
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="True">
    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Select_button" CommandArgument ='<%# Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="SelectRow" ForeColor="#8C4510" runat="server">Select</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>

       <%-- <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True"></asp:CommandField>--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Firstname" SortExpression="Firstname">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Firstname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Firstname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Firstname") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Middlename" SortExpression="Middlename">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Middlename") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Middlename" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Middlename") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lastname" SortExpression="Lastname">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lastname") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Lastname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Lastname") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Age" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sex" SortExpression="Sex">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sex") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Sex" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sex") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

    <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />

</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your in-place updatable controls in an AJAX `UpdatePanel`.

This should mean that your page will not reload when those specific controls are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove one of the grid command onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" or         onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging".